# sys_write will not output 0x0A

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am making a calculator in assembly for practice. It is working fine except for when the answer is displayed, the new line character (0x0A) will not display. Instead there is a box with the numbers 0014 inside (Unicode probably). Am I doing something wrong?

```
bits 64 ; 64-bit (amd64) code

section .data
    stdin: equ 0
    stdout: equ 1

    sys_read: equ 0
    sys_write: equ 1
    sys_exit: equ 60

    l_out1: db "Simple Assembly Addition",0Ah,": "
    l_len1: equ 27
    l_out2: db ": "
    l_len2: equ 2
    l_out3: db "Answer is: "
    l_len3: equ 11
section .bss
    l_in1: resb 3       ; reserve 3 bytes (digits)
    l_in2: resb 3       ; reserve 3 bytes (digits)
    l_ans: resb 4       ; answer
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov rax,sys_write   ; system call id
    mov rdi,stdout      ; descriptor
    mov rsi,l_out1
    mov rdx,l_len1
    syscall

    mov rax,sys_read    ; system call id
    mov rdi,stdin       ; descriptor
    mov rsi,l_in1
    mov rdx,3       ; see .bss
    syscall

    mov rax,sys_write   ; system call id
    mov rdi,stdout      ; descriptor
    mov rsi,l_out2
    mov rdx,l_len2
    syscall

    mov rax,sys_read    ; system call id
    mov rdi,stdin       ; descriptor
    mov rsi,l_in2
    mov rdx,3
    syscall

    mov r8,[l_in1]      ; copy l_in1 to rax
    sub r8,"0"
    mov r9,[l_in2]      ; copy l_in2 to rax
    sub r9,"0"

    add r8,r9
    add r8,"0"      ; add 0 for ascii conversion

    mov [l_ans],r8      ; store answer to address of l_ans

    mov rax,sys_write   ; system call id
    mov rdi,stdout      ; descriptor
    mov rsi,l_out3
    mov rdx,l_len3
    syscall

    mov rax,sys_write   ; system call id
    mov rdi,stdout      ; descriptor
    mov rsi,l_ans
    mov rdx,4
    syscall

    mov rax,sys_write
    mov rdi,stdout
    mov rsi,0Ah
    mov rdx,1
    syscall

    mov rax,sys_exit    ; system call id
    mov rdi,0       ; return 0
    syscall
```

Comment: `sys_write` expects a pointer to memory. You can't do `mov rsi, 0Ah`. You need to place it into memory and load its address just like for the other strings. PS: you do know that this code as-is only works for single digits, right? And you have some size mismatches here and there.

Comment: @Jester this fixed the new line problem, but what about the DC4 (u+0014) character.

Comment: You print 4 bytes, but only 1 is set to meaningful value, that's why you get extra stuff (and even that is done wrong - you use a 64 bit register to write to 4 bytes of space). The printed character is actually the two newlines from the inputs added together because you forgot to operate on a single byte only.

Comment: @Jester No I did not know it only works for single digits (I just started learning this language yesterday, and I though there were 255 possible numbers in each byte), and I do not know what 'operating on a single byte' means.

Comment: Yes, each byte has 256 possible values, but those are binary. You have text input, so each byte is only a single digit. You operate using full 64 bits registers, instead of the appropriate size (1 byte in this case). To utilize the 256 values per byte, you need to convert to and from binary.